# Override tendency to avoid filling entire page with floats

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column

I'm working on a two column document, and on one of the pages, I want to fill an entire column with three different floats.  But when I use, for instance, h!, ht!, b, b!, t!, etc., on all three of them (or any combination of these), I get two in one column and one in the other.  Is there a package or something that fixes this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I want to keep a bunch of figures together, I simply use one `figure` environment:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{foo}
    \caption{Foo}
    \vspace{5mm}
    \includegraphics{bar}
    \caption{Baz}
    \vspace{5mm}
    \includegraphics{bar}
    \caption{Baz}
\end{figure}
```

It looks a bit strange, but it works. You can have multiple `\caption`s in one `figure` environment.

Now there is no way Latex can place these three figures on different columns or different pages. You can fine-tune `\vspace`s to your needs.

Comment: This is sort of tricky because you need to then play with LaTeX's float parameters to prevent it from trying to place the figure on a page of floats or simply failing to place it at all. You can also stick the contents of the figure environment inside a `\vbox to\textheight{...}` and use `\vfill` to separate the floats without having to play with manual spacing.

Comment: I like this answer the best.  Even though it's a little more hackish than @TH.'s answer, it's much simpler and it works best for me.  Thanks to everyone for all of your answers!

Comment: This answer together with Will Robertson's (using [p]) solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way to handle this is to use the `afterpage` package along with the `float` package's `H` specifier. Here's a complete example.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\afterpage{
        \begin{figure}[H]
        \fbox{Top figure}
        \caption{Top figure}
        \end{figure}
        \vfill
        \begin{figure}[H]
        \fbox{Middle figure}
        \caption{Middle figure}
        \end{figure}
        \vfill
        \begin{figure}[H]
        \fbox{Bottom figure}
        \caption{Bottom figure}
        \end{figure}
        \newpage
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Another option is to use the `p` float placement specifier outside of the `\afterpage`. There's no guarantee that those three will appear together with that.

Answer (score 2):

In two-column mode, a "column" is equivalent to a "page" in one-column mode. So if you want three floats in one column on their own, simply specify the `[p]` float option. For example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\rule{10em}{10em}
\caption{A black box.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\rule{10em}{10em}
\caption{A black box.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\rule{10em}{10em}
\caption{A black box.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but couldn't figure out how to ensure that only those floats would appear on the page and that they would all appear on the page.

Comment: Right, your method is better if you want to ultimately constrain where the floats end up.

Answer (score 0):

simplest and obvious answer for me...

```
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
    .....
\end{figure}

\vfill

\begin{figure}
    .....
\end{figure}

\clearpage
```

that way the figures will be alone in 1 page, wherever latex will place them
the alternative is having 1 figure for all images but still use `\clearpage`